# Unable to log onto Oracle unless a add "AS SYSADMIN" after the user name

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, datagrip

From the SQL Plus, When adding "AS SYSADMIN" after the user name:

> UserName AS SYSADMIN

I am able to log on after entering my password

but if I just do the user name:

> UserName

I get the following error message:

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

I need to log on just with the username so that I can configure JetBrains DataGrip

Comment: For the record, did you mean `AS SYSDBA` ?

Answer (score 2):

The `AS SYSxxx` roles are system privileges that should not be overused, as you appear to have correctly surmised. Typically these roles have a separate authentication source than the normal user account - in other words they may have their own password, which is generally stored in a separate location.

Try this:

1. While logged in as SYSADMIN, reset the user's password with an `ALTER USER [username] IDENTIFIED BY [password];` command.
2. Log out.
3. Log in as the user, without `AS SYSADMIN`, using the new password value.

You should still be able to log in `AS SYSADMIN` using the old password. To sync them, have someone with `SYSDBA` privilege regrant the `SYSADMIN` privilege to your user. If you are working in an Oracle RAC configuration, repeat the grant once on each cluster node, as the external password file is only updated on the local instance when the grant is issued.